# XCode Swift Getting the coding to get device console log file

Tags: swift, xcode

I would using Swift to create the application.
In this application, it would need to connect to some framework.
However, the function on framework only using the NSLog to display the data, also it doesn't have any return variable on the function.

Would I have any method to read the NSLog on the code and find out the result?
I would need save the result into my device and database.

Additional information:

1. I cannot edit the Framework. I only can read the .h file
2. The framework function only return the (Bool) as their result, but the KEY DATA would store in NSLog.

Here is the function on the header(.h) file

/**

- @discussion Sync data (from a certain date to today)
- Required:isHasDataStatus = YES
- 
- @param  time From that day. Format:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm e.g. @"2018-08-30-09-30"
- @param  type See UTEDeviceDataType
- 
- @return It sends successfully or fails
- 

*/

- (BOOL)syncDataCustomTime:(NSString *_Nonnull)time type:(UTEDeviceDataType)type;

NSLog Return :
2021-06-07 12:46:55.428269+0800 app_function_test[19819:7599770] record***time = 2021-05-11-11,Total count = 55

Comment: That seems like a poorly-designed framework... Do you have access to the source for it? If so, rewrite it so that there are return values. Trying to read and parse the output seems like a needless hoop to jump through, especially if you have to parse different data types out of it.

Comment: Thank you reply. I cannot edit the framework.

Comment: Maybe you have misunderstood the framework API, could you give an example of a function in the API from the h.file?

Comment: On top of what others have said, not only does this seem like a poorly-designed framework, but trying to parse NSLog output seems like a very unreliable and inefficient solution. Maybe try contacting the developer of the framework? It's hard to help without knowing more information about the root problem.

Comment: I uploaded the header information on the question, As I know, this function [(BOOL)syncDataCustomTime]
 would only return the boolean on the result.